# Does explicit type cast from double to integer always check for integer overflow?

Tags: c++, casting

I did some testing with some online compiler and by using explicit type casting it prevent over/underflow automatically.

For example from double 999999999999999999 to uint32, the result is the largest uint32 number. My question is where is the feature coming from? Is it standard C/C++ or is compiler specific? Thanks.

example:

```
double a;
a = 999999999999999999.0;
int b;
b = a;
```

online compiler: codeinterview.io
offline: Visual Studio 2019 community (latest stable version)

Comment: please provide which compiler and parameters you used

Comment: please be explicit about what you mean with "explicit type casting". Please include a [mcve]

Comment: MSVC: https://msvc.godbolt.org/z/qpL5aB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When converting from a floating point number to an integer,

"The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type."

https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.fpint#1

Answer (score 1):

From the 1998 C++ standard, section 4.9 para 1

> An rvalue of a floating point type can be converted to an rvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded. The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type.

Similar clauses exist in all C++ standards.

So the conversion being done by the OP gives undefined behaviour.